# UITableView vs UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

I am working on an animation application.  I would like to have an horizontal UITableView or horizontal UIScrollView that will show little images representing a drawing at page X.

Since that my animation app can easily have 200 drawings, this means that my UITableView or UIScrollView can contain 200 images.

Finally, I would like to implement UIAnimation, where the user will be able to reorder the images by drag and dropping.  I would like to have something smooth...

I have 2 questions :

1. Which classes is the better for memory management?  I think I understood UITableView automaticly unload cells that are off screen, not UIScrollView.  Is that true?
2. Which one might be easier to implement, considering possible heavy load? (I found this for horizontal UITableView : [EasyTableView](https://github.com/alekseyn/EasyTableView)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should look into tiling with UIScrollView. There have been some very good sessions talking about advanced use of UIScrollView at WWDC over the past three years, and the videos of those sessions are available if you're a registered developer. They'll show you how to use UIScrollView's tiling feature to load just the content that you need, much as UITableView loads only the content that it needs.

As far as I'm aware, UITableView doesn't work in a horizontal mode, so UIScrollView is currently your only choice if you're only considering classes in Cocoa Touch. I'm sure there are some third party options, but I don't know enough to recommend one.

Comment: yes I am registered dev, I will look into that tomorow.  If by any chance, you have the title of the video, it will be greaty apreciated! =) thx

Comment: [Advanced ScrollView Techniques](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=104) from 2011 is a good place to start.